# Settings mentioned in .prettierrc not working

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-standard

I am using Eslint and prettier for formatting in my react project. This combination was working fine until now but  all of a sudden the prettier has stopped doing the formatting. 
However, I can see in the output that prettier is actually running but it is just not doing the formatting.
The output which I am getting is

> ["INFO" - 5:48:35 PM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc
>   or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used ["INFO" -
>   5:48:35 PM] Prettier Options:
>
> {   "filepath": "./src",   "parser": "babel",   "tabWidth": 2,
>   "semi": true,   "singleQuote": true,   "trailingComma": "all",
>   "bracketSpacing": true,   "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
>   "arrowParens": "always",   "requirePragma": true,   "printWidth": 100,
>   "max-len": ["warn", 100],   "useTabs": true,   "rangeStart": 0,
>   "insertPragma": false }
>
> ["INFO" - 5:48:35 PM] Formatting completed in 53.9165ms.

It says that formatting is completed but no formatting takes place in actual.

However, if I remove the .prettierrc file from the root then it does the formatting with default configuration but why is it not doing the formatting mentioned in .prettierrc file ?